# Azure serverless functions: input binding DataType "stream" not supported

Tags: node.js, azure, stream, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

The goal is to receive in Azure HttpTrigger multipart form (with a text file) in the stream and pipe it to the Azure Blob Storage. While processing, check if the file exceeds `SIZE_LIMIT` (20 Megabytes), then abort uploading.

Tried to set up `function.js` like this

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["post"],
      "dataType": "stream",
      "route": "myroute"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

But in debug I see in the variable `req.body` Buffer type.
What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to receive stream in Azure Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, it's by design that Nodejs(non-C#) functions read the incoming content as Buffer.

Here's the [thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1361) tracking the stream support but it seems not in progress. We may have to operate on the buffer(convert to stream and so on) based on our requirement.

Comment: So there is no options to validate size of incoming file to prevent memory issues?

Comment: @MichaelPikanin I think you are right, no option to validate before the file is loaded in memory.